# Firebase still making two rooms in one to one chat app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with chat app on android. Here is my code, where I'm creating room.

```
public void goToChat(View view) {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        final Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        final String sender = senderName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String receiver = receiverName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String room_name_1 = sender + "_" + receiver;
        final String room_name_2 = receiver + "_" + sender;

        map.put(room_name_1,"");
        System.out.println(room_name_1);
        System.out.println(room_name_2);

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_name_1))
                {
                    System.out.println("ROOM1");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chat.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Room_name", room_name_1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_name_2))
                {
                    System.out.println("ROOM2");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chat.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Room_name",room_name_1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if((dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_name_1) == false) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_name_2) == false))
                {
                    System.out.println("ROOM3");
                    databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chat.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Room_name",room_name_1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I know that it might look better, but I'm new to android.

Here is how database looks:

[image: click!]

I've spent a lot of time coding and I just can't see where the problem lies, but it seems that it's in this part. The point is, that when I'm trying to enter to room that was made it's okay, everything is fine. But in the image above I want to have those two rooms as one.

BTW first post here, yay!

Answer (score 2):

why not create a pattern to create room name? for example :

```
if(sender.compareTo(receiver)<0)
    room_name = sender + "_" + receiver;
else
    room_name = receiver + "_" + sender;
```

thus, we just need to check the existence of single node only.

And also, I think the last else, should be enough with "else" only not "else if"

I don't know the performance of checking whether a child exist is fast or not.
But as a good developer (and to save money.. hehehe), we should minimize unnecessary database connection.

Comment: Sure, but You know what they say, a drowning man clutches at straws, especially drowning newbie :D .Now I'm refactoring code :D .

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_name_1))
                {
                    System.out.println("ROOM1");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chat.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Room_name", room_name_1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_name_2))
                {
                    System.out.println("ROOM2");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chat.class);
                    /*
                     Now is okay...
                    */
                    intent.putExtra("Room_name",room_name_2);   
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```